# jQuery - always on top

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to make an element to be always on top with jQuery? I could use `z-index` in CSS, but in Internet explorer 7 it works only with `position:relative;` and the `position` must be `absolute`. So maybe there is something what I can do with jQuery?

Now my jQuery file looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#mainmenu li.item').hover(function(){
        $('.sub',this).show();
    },
    function(){
        $('.sub',this).hide();
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#mainmenu li .sub{
    text-transform:lowercase;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    top: 31px;
    left: 0px;
    background:url("images/sub-menu-bg.png") repeat-x;
    z-index:6;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    padding-top:15px;
    width: 280px;
    color: #3e4f77;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

Comment: z-index should work exactly the same with absolute as with relative... even in ie7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many jQuery scripts that fix the z-index issue in IE7

http://www.vancelucas.com/blog/fixing-ie7-z-index-issues-with-jquery/